# Scrolling region in cocos2d version 2

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to implement a help screen in my cocos2d game, using cocos2d version 2.0. My screen will have a title bar ("Help") at the top and then the rest of the screen below that is where I want to put a scrolling help section. Ideally I would be able to put both text and images into this help window.

The problem is that cocos2d does not have any functionality like UIScrollView, and from what I have seen doing Google searches, every custom solution I have found seems to have problems with various bugs popping up on various devices.

I have tried these solutions thus far:

- CCScrollLayer: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/17118/page/3
- Scrolling CCNode: http://tonyngo.net/2011/11/scrolling-ccnode-in-cocos2d/
- CCScrollView: http://bitbattalion.com/2011/09/uikit-uiscrollview-and-cocos2d/

The closest thing I got to work was embedding a UITextView but that seemed to randomly crash after a few scrolls so it seems unreliable to me.

Does anyone know of a good simple robust solution to this problem? It seems like it should be straightforward but it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you make new `class` say:(HelpViewClass) and implement it with an `UIScrollView` and add whatever you want to add on `UIScrollView` and then you can use this as a `child` to your layer.

```
Steps
```

1. Make a class - inherited with UIView
2. Add `UIScrollView` to the View.
3. Add Your components to it.
4. Add this `UIView` to the `HelpLayer`.

You can add any UIKit component to the cocos2d Layer by using this

```
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addSubView:scrollView];
```

Note : Remove all UI component when you go back from this HelpLayer.

I think this may help you !

Comment: Unfortunately this is what the above solutions that I have already tried do. It doesn't work very well. There are random freeze issues with this on various versions of iOS. In some cases you even have to go into the cocos2d source code to try to fix the issues.

Comment: One More thing you can do here you create your own scroll class by using CCSprite ... and implement scroll using ccpAdd and ccpSub on touch move method ..